# QThread not started

Tags: qt, qthread

I followed this [link about QThread](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Although I did everything the same (beside uncommenting error handling), the `Worker::process` is not called.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I think, there is very fundamental problem.

The code:

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(){};
    ~Worker(){};

    public slots:
        void process();

    signals:
        void finished();
        void error(QString err);

private:
    // add your variables here
};

void Worker::process()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nHallo !");
    }
    emit finished();
}

int test_thread()
{
    QThread* thread = new QThread;

    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);


   //QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this,       SLOT(errorString(QString)));
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what does your output think about that?

Comment: 1. `finished` will be never emited. because you have infinite loop. 2. You need to run `QCoreApplication::exec` in your main thread. Without that slots will not be called.

Comment: 1.) is clear  2.) seems to be the problem: Ok - I need always a QCoreApplication running? Should this be started before or afterwards?

Answer (score 4):

You're close, but you're missing some key concepts.

Think about what the code

```
while(1)
{
    printf("\nHallo !");
}
emit finished();
```

is doing. The `finished` signal will never be emitted because of your infinite loop. Try something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
const unsigned int max = 10;
while (++counter < max) {
    print("\nHallo, iteration %d", counter);
}

emit finished();
```

You can see that the useful work is being completed but then the signal `finished` is emitted.

The `QCoreApplication` is the signal broker for the entire application. Without starting this, no signals/slots will be interpreted by the application unless the thread contains it's own signal and slot definitions. **Note**: Direct connections do not require an event loop.

To fix this, insert `QCoreApplication::exec()` between these two lines in your main:

```
thread->start();
// put right here
return 0;
```

Additionally, you'll probably also want to stop the `exec()` when the thread returns, but I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: The problem with the loop is clear. I inserted this afterwards. Think of it to be not present. But the question is: When I call the QCoreApplication::exec() after having started the thread - how can it work? Clear - there are yust a few miscroseconds between, but what happens if the thread already begins to execute and the QCoreApplication is not yet startet?

Comment: @michael What do you expect to happen? `QThread` has its own event loop that it starts when you start the thread. So it will run normally. If any signals are sent to the main thread, they will go to the queue and will be processed after you call `QCoreApplication::exec`.

Comment: `The QCoreApplication is the signal broker for the entire application. Without starting this, no signals/slots will be interpreted by the application.` This is not entirely true. `QThread` has its own event loop, so any slots that live in that thread will be called even without starting the `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: Also direct connections act like function calls. They don't require an event loop.